# Test is failing, gives error - cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Arity mismatch:

Tags: cucumber

I am seeing below error in console log.

cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Arity mismatch: Step Definition 'com.sfg.wef.steps.PolicyOwnersLandingSteps.inOwnerLandingPageIClickButtonOrIClickCompanyContractAndStayOnChecklistIfAny(String,String) in file:/C:/dev/web-external-framework/wef-tests-mma/target/test-classes/' with pattern [^in owner landing page I click (.*) button or I click company (.*) contract/policy (.*) and stay on modal informational page if any$] is declared with 2 parameters. However, the gherkin step has 3 arguments [Partial Withdraw, company, policy number].

Please guide!

Answer (score 1):

The error means you are passing in and writing out an inconsistent number of captured arguments from your regex.

Looking at your snippet (Albeit it is quite hard), it seems as though you're mixing CukeExp and Regexp. Could you paste the code-snippet here and I can try triage for you.

Remember if you're using anchors `^` and `$` you need to use regexp. So start / end your statement with `/` `/`. However CukeExp which is newer and designed to be easier to use, requires you to start and end with a `"` or `'`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Luke Hill for your response. here is the code.

@And("^in owner landing page I click (.*) button if available else I click company (.*) contract/policy (.*)$")
public void inOwnerLandingPageIClickButtonIfAvailableElseIClickCompanyContractPolicy(String buttonName,
String company,
String contractPolicyId) {

```
    inOwnerLandingPageIClickButtonOrIClickCompanyContractAndStayOnChecklistIfAny(buttonName, contractPolicyId);
    // in service-capture modal, click through any checklist messages to proceed through flow
    assertSCLandingPageChecklistMessages(contractPolicyId, buttonName);
}

// when service-capture modal opens, if there are any checklists or informational message displayes where user
// has to decide to proceed by clicking ok or yes - stay on that page and do not click ok/yes
@And("^in owner landing page I click (.*) button or I click company (.*) contract/policy (.*) and stay on modal informational page if any$")
public void inOwnerLandingPageIClickButtonOrIClickCompanyContractAndStayOnChecklistIfAny(String buttonName,
                                                                                         String contractPolicyId) {
    Boolean selectedSC;
    Boolean selectContractPolicy;

    getContractPolicyValues(contractPolicyId);
```

//        isCompanyClient();
Assert.assertTrue(String.format("%s is not eligible to see %s button", contractPolicyId, buttonName),
euiPolicyownerLanding.isEligibleForServiceCaptureButton(buttonName, contractPolicyId, policySummary));

```
    // if landing page displays button then click it, else click on contract/policy from list to go to Summary
    // details page and if Summary page displays button then click it
    selectedSC = euiPolicyownerLanding.clickServiceCaptureButtonOnPage(buttonName, "landing");
    if (!selectedSC) {
        Assert.assertTrue(euiPolicyownerLanding.missingContractPolicy(contractPolicyId));
        selectContractPolicy = euiPolicyownerLanding.selectContractPolicyFromListOnLandingPage(contractPolicyId);
        if (selectContractPolicy) {
            waitForPageLoadComplete(Waf.pageLoadMaxWaitTimeSeconds);
            waitForPageReadiness();
            selectedSC = euiPolicyownerLanding.clickServiceCaptureButtonOnPage(buttonName, "summary");
        }
    }
    if (selectedSC) {
        if (!switchToSpecificWindow("servicecapture")) {
            euiPolicyownerLanding.selectContractPolicyFromListOnMultiPolicyPage(contractPolicyId);
            if (!switchToSpecificWindow("servicecapture")) {
                selectedSC = euiPolicyownerLanding.clickServiceCaptureButtonOnPage(buttonName, "summary");
                if (!selectedSC) {
                    ApplicationError.handleApplicationError();
                    Assert.fail(String.format("After clicking %s button for %s, was unable to switch to %s window",
                            buttonName, contractPolicyId, buttonName));
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        Assert.fail(String.format("Unsuccessful attempt to click %s button for %s, was unable to switch to %s window",
                buttonName, contractPolicyId, buttonName));
    }
    switch (buttonName.toLowerCase()) {
    case "partial withdraw":
            SystematicWithdrawalSteps.currentContractPolicyID = contractPolicyId;
            break;
        default:
            Assert.fail(String.format("Unimplemented button %s", buttonName));
```